# Java RSA decryption and encryption with c#

Tags: c#, java, encryption, rsa

I encrypt a message and then decrypt it. Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/2489899. 
I have to store this keys in a xml scheme, because the message should be able to decrypt in c# too. (This is only a "summary" of my program with the databse and so on). But i always get the Exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:308)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:255)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at Main.decrypt(Main.java:50)
at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Comment: Does your data start with a zero?

Comment: Did any of the answers help?  Is there more information you can provide (or need)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, your RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec constructor call uses an incorrect order of parameters.

Comment: Good catch! I'll just delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the exception and the JavaDoc for [sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/rsa/RSAPadding.html)  and [javax.crypto.BadPaddingException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.html), it looks like your Java code expects PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, but your C code is not using this same padding.  You'll need to make sure the padding algorithm used on both sides is the same.

Comment: I assume you mean PKCS#7 v1.5 padding.

Comment: @Robert: good catch.  Actually, the Javadoc for RSAPadding states that it's using PKCS#1 v1.5 .  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i generated this key in java. I updated my gist (https://gist.github.com/2489899). Now i don't use hard coded keys, but get the same exception.

Comment: Good on you!  Hard coded keys are a security problem, so it's great that you fixed that!  Back to topic, padding is not about key generation, but rather the length of the data being encrypted.  Block ciphers encrypt a "block" of text (usually 8 or 16 bytes at a time), so if your data is not a multiple of the block size, it needs to be padded.  There are many ways to pad your data, but it *must* be the same for both encryption and decryption.  For example, padding with all 0's when encrypting, and expecting all 1's when decrypting, the decryption will be unable to detect where the message ends.